# Get HTML form data into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help with my HTML, I'm attempting to pass my form data to a script called send.js, However nothing happens. I have a feeling my error lies **input type** however im not very good at html

```
<form method="post" name="myform">
  <label for="msg">Message</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="5" cols="50"> </textarea> <br>
  <label for="your_name">Your Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" /> <br>
  <label for="customer_number">Customers Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="customer_number" id="customer_number" /> <br>
<input type="submit" value = "Send Message" onsubmit="f1">
</form>
<script> src="send.js"</script>
```

The send.js scripot is as follows

```
function f1()
{
        var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
        var your_name = document.getElementById("your_name").value;
        var customer_number = document.getElementById("customer_number").value;
        alert("value 1 = " + msg "value 2 = " + your_name "value 3 = " +  customer_number );
}
```

Any input would be greatly apperciated

Comment: Your opening `script` tag is missing its ending `>`.

Comment: "a script called send.js" is not something you can pass data to - you need a *function* - wow, that edit makes less sense than the original error, by the way

Comment: the function is in send,js called f1

Comment: If you show us the function you're using, we can help.

Comment: well, your code will call `f1` on submit, as long as you put `onsubmit` in the right place ... in the `form` tag - since `form` have an `onsubmit` event, but `input` does not - you'll also need to make sure `f1` prevents the default submit behaviour - which in this case is to `post` the data to the URL of the current page

Comment: The `script`'s `src` needs to be specified in the tag. You're currently creating a variable

    `<script src="send.js"></script>`

Comment: please put code **in the question** where it is readable - though, it's not really necessary, since the issue you have is that you've put `onsubmit` on the wrong element

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" name="myform">
  <label for="msg">Message</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="5" cols="50"> </textarea> <br>
  <label for="your_name">Your Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" /> <br>
  <label for="customer_number">Customers Number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="customer_number" id="customer_number" /> <br>
<input type="submit" value = "Send Message" onsubmit="f1">
</form>
<script src="send.js"></script>
```

**send.js**

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = f1();
```

### OR

```
<form method="post" name="myform" onsumbit="f1()">
```